# Искажение цвета элементов при конвертации проекта в Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi

Был проект на Borland Delphi 6. Пришло время переходить на последнюю версию Embarcadero Delphi 10.2. Проект достаточно большой, открылся и построился в новой версии нормально, но! Все элементы `TPanel` изменили цвет с белого (`clWindow`) на общий цвет фона по умолчанию (`clBtnFace`), `TComboBox` - то же самое. Причем в свойствах стоит правильный цвет (`clWindow`). Но если цвет `TPanel` удалось изменить вручную, то цвет `TComboBox` вообще ни на что не реагирует!!!

Что тут можно сделать? Кроме того, что удалить элементы и снова добавить?

Comment: Если удаление и добавление работает, то ищите в чем получается отличие в DFM ..

Comment: 1. Цвет в дизайнере или в откомпилированном приложении? 2. Свойство ParentColor смотрели?

Answer (score 0):

Один из [костыльных] вариантов: при открытии формы пробежаться по всем компонентам формы и поменять им цвет.

```
for i := frmMain.ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  if frmMain.Components[i] is TPanel then TPanel(frmMain.Components[i]).Color := NewColor; //Принудительно меняем цвет
end;
```